# InvalidStateError. Vimeo videos plays okay but throwing an exception

Tags: vimeo

I'm trying to replace image(s) that have data-video1 and data-video2 attributes as video IDs and replace them with two videos (one supersedes the other and second video plays when the first autoplaying video is clicked). All works well but it throws the follwing exception that's breaking my navigation. Could you please advise how I'd fix the code to listen and wait until the videos are ready?

**InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable**

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fitvids/1.2.0/jquery.fitvids.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.homepage-collage > a').each(function(index) {
        $this = $(this);
        $img = $this.find('img');

        if($img.data('video1')){

          var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*100000);
          var rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*100000);
          var rand3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*100000);

          $img.css({'opacity':0}).parent().append('<div class="video-wrap video-wrap'+rand3+'"> <div class="trigger"></div><div class="player1_wrap"><iframe id="player'+rand1+'" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/'+  $img.data('video1') +'?api=1&amp;player_id=player'+rand1+'&amp;autostop=0&amp;badge=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;title=0&amp;background=1&amp;loop=1" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0"></iframe></div><div class="player2_wrap"> <iframe id="player'+rand2+'" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/'+ $img.data('video2') +'?api=1&amp;playsinline=false&amp;player_id=player'+rand2+'&amp;autostop=1&amp;badge=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;title=0&amp;" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0"></iframe> </div> </div>');

          $this.fitVids();

          var player1 = new Vimeo.Player($('#player'+rand1+''));
          var player2 = new Vimeo.Player($('#player'+rand2+''));

          $(document).on('click', '.video-wrap'+rand3+' .trigger', function(event) {
            var $trigger = $(this);
            $trigger.hide();
            player1.pause();
            $trigger.siblings('.player1_wrap').fadeOut('fast');
            $trigger.siblings('.player2_wrap').fadeIn('fast');
            player2.play();
          });

          player2.on('finish', function () {
            $trigger = $('.video-wrap'+rand3+' .trigger');
            $trigger.show();
            $trigger.siblings('.player2_wrap').fadeOut('fast')
            $trigger.siblings('.player1_wrap').fadeIn('fast');
            player1.play();
          });
        }

      });
    });
</script>
```

Any guidance is much appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using Firefox because this is a known issue in Firefox that has been logged in our repository (https://github.com/vimeo/player.js/issues/344). However, not quite sure how this could be breaking your navigation as in all of our tests this error does not seem to have an effect. It more likely is a problem with your code as opposed to the Vimeo API. However, this information would be helpful in potentially allowing me to help you more.

1) What do you mean by "break your navigation"? Can you give an example page either a webpage or JSFiddle?

2) Can you try another browser- Chrome/Safari/Edge? The error shouldn't appear there. If it doesn't and the problem remains, then that error has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking time to help. When I meant it broke the navigation, I meant that the anchors where no longer working. However, on other pages where this code wasn't included, the navigation worked fine. Like you mentioned the error was only being shown on the latest version of Firefox (63.0.1). I've managed to fix the problem with menu with preventPropagation for now. The error doesn't seem to be causing any other problem. Thanks for your help!